# displays blank items in combobox from database

Tags: java

i tried below code in which i want to fetch all values when WHERE condition satisfied..and my M S Access databse contains NULL values also but when i m fetching items from database into combobox i dont want NULL values in my combo...nd below code fetches null values also..

code i tried:

```
 if(e.getSource()==cmb_dest)
    {
             cmb_route.removeAll();

             try
            {
               Connection con;
               DriverManager.registerDriver(new sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver());
               Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
               con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnproj","","");
               Statement s = con.createStatement();
            // String qry="select c_id,p_category from product";
               String qry2="select * from trans_dest where 
               dest='"+cmb_dest.getSelectedItem()+"'";    
               System.out.println(qry2); 
               ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(qry2);
             //ResultSet rs1=s1.executeQuery(qry2);
               while(rs.next())
               {                           
                       cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout1"));
                       cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout2"));
                       cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout3"));
                       cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout4"));
               }   
            }
             catch(Exception re)
             {
                 System.out.println(re.getMessage());
             }
        }
```

there is no error but combobox contains blank items also....

Comment: can you give us an example to a row in your table-trans_dest?

Comment: Tip: pay attention to code format. Don't you realize that's something wrong when you see this horrible mess of randomly indented code?

Answer (score 2):

you need to build an object with 4 fields in order to do you you want to do

```
           while(rs.next())
           {                           
                   cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout1"));
                   cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout2"));
                   cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout3"));
                   cmb_route.add(rs.getString("rout4"));
           }
```

insted of this you need to

```
           your_object vo = null;
           while(rs.next())
           {       
                   vo = new your_object();
                   vo.setRout1(rs.getString("rout1"));
                   vo.setRout2(rs.getString("rout2"));
                   vo.setRout3(rs.getString("rout3"));
                   vo.setRout4(rs.getString("rout4"));
                   cmb_route.add(vo);

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

[getString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) from `ResultSet` returns `null` if the column's value is SQL `NULL` . so just check the returned value against java `null` and only if it is not add it to you list

```
String rout1 = rs.getString("rout1");
if(rout1 != null) {
    cmb_route.add(rout1);
}
```

Comment: cool! how about an accept so that your question doesn't stay opened/unanswered? and maybe an up-vote too ;-)